# Error installing cgal from source in amazon linux AMIs

Tags: cmake, installation, cgal, amazon-ami

I'm trying to install cgal on amazon linux AMI(deep learning). When i run command `cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DCGAL_HEADER_ONLY=ON .`, I get following error(i haven't edited or opened the make files)

> CMake Error: Error in cmake code at
>   /home/ec2-user/CGAL-4.12.1/CMakeLists.txt:1377: Parse error.  Function
>   missing ending ")".  End of file reached.

Same thing runs nicely on my ubuntu 18.04. 
How to rectify this?

Comment: [One of the worst error message in CMake: it tells the reason, but do not point to the line with the function's definition, it shows only the number of lines in the file itself.] As far as I understand, this kind of error may only be affected by CMake version, it doesn't depend on the machine configuration, project's configuration, etc. What CMake version do you use?

Comment: @ Tsyvarev Thank you, upgraded cmake from 2.8 to 3.12 and it's working.

Comment: Yes, CMake 2.8" version is too old. The project has `cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.1)` at the top, but before any instruction is executed, the script is needed to be parsed.